# App won't find directory I created in Linux

Tags: linux, debian, mount, dosbox

I installed Doxbox-x by Snapcraft in a Debian 10 Linux. It was running ok. I created a directory `doswin` in the root to put my dos and windows stuff. Now when I try to mount the directory inside Dosbox, it just say the directory doesn't exists. I don't know what I did.

The DOS command I use is a simple `mount c /doswin`, and if I try to mount the directory `usr` it works. But if I create a directory inside `usr`, it just won't appear in the list inside Dosbox-x when I try a DIR dos command. Dosbox-x, as it seems, will only see the old directories created by Linux itself when installed / configured. Though it might be a ownership issue but I don't know how to deal with.

Any ideas?